# How can I config the peer node connect to the orderer service on another port than 7050?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, peer

I am trying to create a new peer node that connects to existing fabric network on another machine. However, when I try to connect, there is an error message. The message is :

> " Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to any of the
>   endpoints: [orderer:7050] "

I wish to ask how can I config the peer node so that it can connect to the orderer service on another port than 7050.
config in the env of container.

Comment: Are you going through the create and join channel flow?  The address(es) of the ordering node(s) are part of the channel definition.